# Microsoft visual studio file not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I was trying to make a basic program that would print out the words "hello" and then "press any key to continue" but whenever I try to run the code, this pops up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMkSM.jpg)

This is my code btw,

```
    #include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << 'hello\n';
    system('pause');
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Your code is wrong and may fail into compilation error. Can you execute this? `int main(){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Try fixing that first not to fail into compilation error.

- `#include <cstdlib>` is missing while using `system()`
- A implementation-defined integer is passed to `system()` instead of a pointer to string, which `system()` requires. You should use `""`, not `''`, to express string literals.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    system("pause");
}
```